# Format Java Double to be 7 characters

Tags: java, format, double

I have a lot of Java doubles.  In order to display on the GUI correctly, they can only be 7 characters long, including -negative sign and .period

So let's say it's like:

```
12345.7890
1.34567890
-23.567890
```

I want

```
12345.7
1.34567
-23.567
```

And in rare case it goes over 7 characters before the decimal, just keep 1 decimal place.  Rounded properly preferred.

I'm not versed in all the string/double operations in Java to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
    double d = -23.5678900;
    int precision = d < 0 ? 5 : 6;
    BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(d, new MathContext(precision));
```

it also provides rounding. Maybe it makes sense to add a check for overflow

```
    if (d > 9999999 | d < -999999) {
        System.out.println("#######");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this approach if you want for display purpose only...

```
 Double d = -1.151266662625;
    String str = d.toString();
    String result = Str.substring(0,7);

if(result.contains("."){
// it is according to your need
}else{
// iF dot is not present do what ever you want to do. Either again truncte the string upto 5 place and add ".0" in end of the string

}
```

Comment: with this it is possible that if the decimal value is large there wont be any fractional value. what if the value is 1234567.123456

Comment: @NarendraPathai You are a programmer just apply logics for your problem. Wait I am updating the post

Comment: +1 for editing the answer. your solution did not take care of the conditions the question demanded.

Comment: @NarendraPathai I know that is why I have written in starting only

"Use this approach if you want for display purpose only..."

Answer (score 1):

Well the  standard way to do it is using [DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
Double d = 12345.7890d;

NumberFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("-#####.##");

System.out.println(decimalFormat.format(d));
```